# include Makefile in a makefile and passing defines

Tags: c, makefile

I am tring to pass a define 'CWROOT' to a make file that is is included in an other makefile.
Like:
main.mk

```
$(info before top.mk CWROOT=$(CWROOT))
$(info before top.mk HC12LIB=$(HC12LIB))
include $(SRCDIR)\top.mk
$(info after top.mk CWROOT=$(CWROOT))
$(info after top.mk HC12LIB=$(HC12LIB))
```

where top.mk contains:

```
$(info int top.mk CWROOT=$(CWROOT))
TOOLSDIR = $(CWROOT)\Prog
HC12LIB  = $(CWROOT)\lib
```

I run the  make file with the following command:

```
C:\gmake\make.exe -p -f main.mk CWROOT="C:\Programs\Freescale\CodeWarS12" S12X
```

then I get back:

```
before top.mk CWRoot=C:\Programs\Freescale\CodeWarS12
before top.mk HC12LIB=
after top.mk CWRoot=C:\Programs\Freescale\CodeWarS12
after top.mk HC12LIB=\lib
```

Why do I not get back?

```
after top.mk HC12LIB=C:\Programs\Freescale\CodeWarS12\lib
```

In other words why is CWROOT not passed to the top.mk?

And  why do I not see the $(info) text from the top.mk?

Thanx,
Frank

Comment: Cannot reproduce. As your snippets here are full of small typos, I had to create my own similar example. I guess you have misspelled variable names and similar ...

Comment: You aren't seeing the `int top.mk` message at all in your example output. Are you sure you are dealing with the makefiles you think you are? If you add `-d` to the make command line does it show you that it is loading the files you think it should be?

Comment: With the -d I get: "Reading makefile 'C:\Users\engelsflm\AppData\Local\LocalDoc\Move\S12X_Target_R2009a\Implementatio‌​n\Src\top.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...". Does the "no ~ expansion" mean that the defines are not passed to the top.mk. How do I turn the expansion on?